# How to run two thread groups consecutively in a loop

Tags: jmeter

Is there any way to run two `ThreadGroup` consecutively in a loop for a certain amount of time? I am writing a test scenario in which I have to create a task for multiple users and then fulfill this task by them. Therefore, I decided to divide the scenario into two thread groups, because it needs one user to create a task and many users to complete it. Everything works fine, but the problem arises when I try to run the test in several iterations.

I tried to check `Run Test Group consecutively` check-box, but tests instead of performing alternately, e.g.

```
ThreadGroup 1
ThreadGroup 2
ThreadGroup 1
ThreadGroup 2
```

perform as follows

```
ThreadGroup 1
ThreadGroup 1
ThreadGroup 2
ThreadGroup 2
```

Is it possible to somehow make thread groups execute alternately? I would be very grateful for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run multiple iterations you need to let thread group 2 know that the task is ready and let thread group 1 know that the task is compete and it's ok to generate a new task.

There are 2 approaches of passing data between Thread Groups:

1. [__setProperty()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) function to create/update a value in one Thread Group and [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) to read the value in another Thread Group
2. [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-inter-thread-communication-plugin-in-jmeter), see [SynchronizationExample.jmx](https://jmeter-plugins.org/editor/?utm_source=jpgc&utm_medium=openurl&utm_campaign=examples#/img/examples/SynchronizationExample.jmx) for reference implementation

Comment: I understand, but have a question about first approach. What property should I set in `ThreadGroup 1` to let `ThreadGroup 2` know that the task is ready?